# PHP how to add values to array by function?

Tags: php, arrays, function

I want do add values to array in my function to show movies:

```
$movies = array();

function find_movie($tag) {

    // SELECT MOVIE BY %TAG%

    $movies[] = $MOVIE;

    return '<a href="'.$MOVIE.'">WATCH MOVIE</a>';

}
```

Induction:

```
echo find_movie('cars'); // <a href="cars-movie.html">WATCH MOVIE</a>
```

My problem is here -> `$movies` array is empty...
I want to have array with all movies what is showed.

How can I do that ?

Comment: you can do that by simply adding `global $movies` inside your function or just follow call by reference

Comment: @shatheesh: No, [don't do that](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5166527/1438393). Pass them as parameters as shown in Shankar's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the `$movies` array as a reference to make this work out.

Like this..

```
function find_movie($tag,&$movies){
```

and call it like..

```
echo find_movie('cars',$movies);
```

#### The code..

```
<?php

$movies = array();

function find_movie($tag,&$movies) {
    $movies[] = "<a href=$tag>WATCH MOVIE</a>";

}

find_movie('cars',$movies);
var_dump($movies);
```

**`OUTPUT:`**

```
array (size=1)
  0 => string '<a href=cars>WATCH MOVIE</a>' (length=28)
```

Comment: Thats what i wanted, thank u!